# Front-end Image Upload with Preview - Is this Possible in WP?

Tags: uploads, images

I created a front-end form and have several image upload fields.  I was able to create a post and have the images attached.  But what I would like to do is have the user see a preview of the image they are about to upload before submitting the Post.

I've read quite a few alternatives, Uploadify, Valums.com http://valums.com/ajax-upload, SWFupload and a few others I can't remember.  But the problem with all of them is that once i implement them in the form, the images are no longer attached to the post, but only uploaded to the server.

Any suggestion or code sample I can use to do this?  I have scoured the net for an answer - perhaps it's just not possible in WP to preview an image and also attach it to a post in one form?

Answer (score 3):

Just add this scripts in header

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var blank="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif";
     function readURL(input) {
       if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
           $('#img_prev')
           .attr('src', e.target.result)
           .height(100);
         };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
      else {
      var img = input.value;
        $('#img_prev').attr('src',img).height(200);
    }
    $("#x").show().css("margin-right","10px");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#img_prev").attr("src",blank);
    $("#x").hide();  
  });
});
</script>
```

Add for Internet explorer:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Add style to the header.

```
<style>
 article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
 #x { display:none; position:relative; z-index:200; float:right}
 #previewPane { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Note this should be added in header of that page or ur theme
and this will be upload bar
with preview
u can also cancel the preview with this

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /><br/>


<span id="previewPane">
 img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
 span id="x">[X]</span> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Please format your answer correctly. All code should have an intent of four spaces to create copy able area for scripts, code and CSS. ... If that makes sense.

Comment: You shouldn't be manually loading jQuery like that either.

Comment: I will take care next time

Comment: Regarding jQuery: WordPress contains it anyway, do not load it from Google directly. Also, within this snippet, there is nothing which cannot be done easily without jQuery. The opposite is true: jQuery tempts to favour short syntax over efficient code, like repeating the expensive command `$("#x")`  unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

how can i apply this code to a wpjobsearch plugin ?

the input looks like this :
input id="job_attach_files"
name="job_attach_files[]
type="file"
class="upload jobsearch-upload
multiple="multiple"
onchange="jobsearch_job_attach_files_url(event)